# Microsoft Graph permissions issue when using managed identity and DefaultAzureCredential

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-managed-identity

I have set up a test project that follows this microsoft guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-powershell

The only difference that I made from that tutorial is the code portion. I changed it to look like this:

```
TokenCredential tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(tokenCredential, scopes);

var group = graphClient.Groups["<my-group-id>"].Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Everything works as expected when I publish the website and access it, but when I run this code locally I receive

```
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

I am signed into VS using the same account that I am using in Azure portal (it's a global admin account). Is there any other configuration setting that I am missing so that I can run this code and test locally?

Answer (score 0):

1. Usually you need one of the following permissions to query groups i.e delegated and application permissions : `GroupMember.Read.All, Group.Read.All, Directory.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All User.Read.All`
2. Run VS as administrator and also give user administrator role.

[image]

- But visual studio may not work  in this case . So please try with
  different credential type  like  client secret/certificate credential
  with your app .
- In local debugging ,use  **`Shared Token Cache Credential`** ,as in
  your local environment, DefaultAzureCredential uses the shared token
  credential from the IDE.
- In  Visual Studio, you can set the account that you want  to use when
  debugging using VS : ***`under Options -> Azure Service Authentication.`***

[image]

Please check [Azure Managed Service Identity And Local Development  by  Rahul Nath (rahulpnath.com)](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-managed-service-identity-and-local-development/?utm_source=site-bookmark)

If multiple accounts are  configured, try to set the SharedTokenCacheUsername property to that  specific  account to use.

```
var azureCredentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions();
 azureCredentialOptions.SharedTokenCacheUsername = "<azure ad User Name>";
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(azureCredentialOptions);
```

**Reference:** [DefaultAzureCredential: Unifying How We Get Azure AD Token | Rahul Nath (rahulpnath.com)](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/defaultazurecredential-from-azure-sdk/#:%7E:text=In%20your%20local%20environment%2C%20DefaultAzureCredential%20uses%20the%20shared,log%20in%20to%20Visual%20Studio%20does%20appear%20here.)